# Rewrite rule meaning

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mod_rewrite: what does this RewriteRule do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102128/mod-rewrite-what-does-this-rewriterule-do)

Hi,

Sorry to bother you.

What's the meaning of this rule ?

**RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]**

Thanks in advance.

Bye

Answer (score 1):

That rule applied to all URL patterns (^.*$ matches anything) and [NC,L] means ignore case and don't apply any more rules.

So basically it's making your URL paths case insensitive.

For details, see [here (apache.org)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

Comment: Thanks but '-' stand for what ?

Comment: It means the path shouldn't be changed