# Apache RewriteRule, - (dash) as substitution

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I often see in PHP MVC applications an Apache `RewriteRule` that looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

The [Apache docs for the `RewriteRule` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) states:

> A dash indicates that no substitution
> should be performed (the existing path
> is passed through untouched). This is
> used when a flag (see below) needs to
> be applied without changing the path.

So from what I gather, you can use this to transform a path using a flag i.e `[NC]` for the `RewriteRule`s to follow?

Could someone please explain this dash `RewriteRule` a little better?

Comment: I used this "do nothing" syntax to prevent parent folder's .htaccess rules from executing. It was useful with Apache 2.2. If you're using Apache 2.4, you can just use `RewriteOptions IgnoreInherit` to avoid parent folder's rewriting rules.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See this answer:

[mod_rewrite: what does this RewriteRule do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102128/mod-rewrite-what-does-this-rewriterule-do/2102189#2102189)

It essentially means "do nothing if the previous RewriteConds match". The next RewriteRule(s) will instead do something else when the RewriteConds don't match. In the case of the post i linked you to, the next RewriteRule rewrites the url including "index.php".

Comment: So it's kinda of like an else operator. Or it's the same as prefixing an exclamation mark (!) to all my RewriteCond? I did try search for the answer but they were all relating to RewriteRules and escaping dashes.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, using the dash as target makes mostly sense if last [L] is applied?

Answer (score 11):

I know this is kinda old, but it basically says "Hey, i might wanna use Rewrite, but for urls that match the above RewriteCond(s), leave it be and stop."

EX:

```
# If file or directory exists, we wanna send them there
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Otherwise, use our smart page handler!
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ virtualPage.php?page=$1 [L]
```