# Translate htaccess rewrite rule for nginx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to translate the following apache htaccess rewrite rule for nginx.

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule ^(.+) - [PT,L]
 RewriteRule ^(.+) /index.php
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The apache rewrite rules are explained clearly [in the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102128/mod-rewrite-what-does-this-rewriterule-do/2102189#2102189), especially that special dash "-" rule for non-substitution. This can be rewritten as a [try_files](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files) directive in nginx.

Your question doesn't list a rule for the empty string (home page) (only has non-empty string (.+)). So I'll assume you've had one rule for the home page somewhere else. The rule in nginx could be

```
location = / {
   # your nginx rule matching the empty string (for your home page)
}

# all other locations try in the order: file => directory => index.php
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```